# Proof of Equivalence of algebraic and geometric cross product.

Tags: calculus

This question has not been asked. I used the exact  wording as a similar question replacing "dot" with "cross".  There is a proof using the law of cosines and the distributive law, very elegant I may say that shows the algebraic definition of DOT product is exactly and I mean exactly the geometric definition of the dot product.  I am looking for the CROSS product equivalence. There is much ado about the MAGNITUDE of the cross product being equal to a geometric representation using cosine of the angle between the vectors. That is easy to do! That is NOT what I have been looking for. If anyone can help it is appreciated but you will be the first to do it because I have found no teachers, textbooks, videos, wiki articles or swirling derbies for that matter. Thank you

Comment: Can you say what your geometric definition of $u \times v$ is, in particular how one finds which direction in space it points, and how the geometry gives the length of it?

Comment: It is the area of the parallelogram formed by $\mathbf u,\mathbf v \text{ and } \mathbf u+\mathbf v.$  In two dimensions it is very easy to show that this equals $|x_1y_2 - x_2y_1|$

Comment: The algebraic definition is a matrix , the scalar of each component is the minor determinant for each of x,y,z components of the vector and the geometric definition  is the length of the vectors times the sine of the angle between them times the normal unit vector. Show these are equivalent. It may be easy like you say but I can't find it referenced in any textbook or internet resource. Look at exactly what I am asking.

Comment: The full proof of the equivalence of the algebraic and geometric definition is usually left out of textbooks or assigned as an exercise because it is messy and takes up lots of space. The messy step of the proof, which uses the Law of Cosines, is in showing that $\vert A\times B\vert^2=\vert A\vert^2\vert B\vert^2-(A\cdot B)^2$.

Comment: If that is the case then assume the above statement is true can it then be shown the geometric definition is the same as the algebraic definition?